# Is there a way to improve the data transfer rate between Puppeteer and NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Before I ask my question, I'm pretty sure the answer is no but still, there's no shame in asking.

I'm trying to use THREE+Puppeteer as a render engine on the server-side. It means I can generate 3D images in NodeJs using WebGL on a headless browser. It works perfectly, except for the performance I'm getting out of it. And to my surprise, the bottleneck is not 3D rendering but transferring the rendered image to NodeJs!

Consider the following code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const {
    performance,
    PerformanceObserver
} = require('perf_hooks');

const profiling = {};
const obs = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
    const entry = list.getEntries()[0];
    if (profiling[entry.name]) {
        profiling[entry.name].push(entry.duration);
    } else {
        profiling[entry.name] = [entry.duration];
    }
});
obs.observe({entryTypes: ['measure'], buffered: false});


const pup = puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [
        '--use-gl=swiftshader',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--enable-surface-synchronization',
    ]
}).then(async browser => {
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 720});

    await page.exposeFunction('mark', (name) => {
        performance.mark(name);
    });

    await page.exposeFunction('measure', (name, start, end) => {
        performance.measure(name, start, end);
    });

    //TODO: Load a web page or write a script to instantiate a scene
    // using THREE.js (I've tested with WebGLRenderer)

    for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
        window.mark('evaluate-init');
        const txt = await page.evaluate(async () => {
            window.mark('browser_context-init');
            //Render your scene, you can also make a change to the scene just to make sure
            // it will be rendered and you won't just be returning a cache.
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            const canvas = renderer.domElement;
            const txt = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.mark('browser_context-end');
            window.measure('browser_context', 'browser_context-init', 'browser_context-end');
            return txt;
        });
        window.mark('evaluate-end');
        window.measure('evaluate', 'evaluate-init', 'evaluate-end');

        performance.mark("node_context-init");
        const data = txt.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
        const png = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
        //TODO: You can do something with the png
        performance.mark("node_context-end");
        performance.measure("node_context", "node_context-init", "node_context-end");
    }

    const profiling_results = {};
    for (let name of Object.keys(profiling)) {
        const sum = profiling[name].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        const count = profiling[name].length;
        const avg = (sum / count).toFixed(2);
        profiling_results[name] = avg;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(profiling_results, null, 2));
});
```

Based on my tests, these are the averages for each section:

```
evaluate: 113.49 ms
browser_context: 0.16 ms
node_context: 5.29 ms
```

From my perspective, 113.49 - 0.16 is the time spent to transfer the data from the headless browser to the NodeJs memory. And as you can see, it's the main portion of the time spent by far.

Now after all this, my question is: Is there any way I can improve the performance of the data transfer between Puppeteer and NodeJs?

Comment: I guess there is some overhead to the conversion to string and back again... does `canvas.getImageData()` improve it at all?

Comment: Although it goes via the [devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Runtime/#type-RemoteObject) (which i think is via websocket) so might end up stringified anyway.

Comment: I've done more granular profiling and the majority part of the time spent is actually in transferring the data from the browser context to the NodeJs context. Also, Puppeteer does not support binary data which means using base64 is inevitable.

Comment: What's your end goal? There might be another way around the browser > node bridge.

Comment: That would be great. My end goal is somewhat explained in the question. I'm trying to render a 3D scene and write it to a live feed (a fake webcam). But right now, the frame rate is too slow and the live feed is like 5 frames per second.

Comment: Where do you see that Puppeteer doesn't support binary data? What happens if you return atob(txt) ?

Comment: I don't recall where did I read it (maybe a ticket on github). But you can conduct a very simple test and see the results. I don't remember if it simply returns nothing or it actually throws an error. But in any case, that part of sure of.

Comment: Try a [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) server in node and streaming the image buffer data from the browser app directly to that. You can still use puppeteer to manage the process if needed, just not for the data transfer

Comment: assuming you have already looked at the node canvas/gl implementations

Comment: @Matt I have looked into using THREE without a browser but I could not make it work. If you have a working example, I'll be grateful to you if you share it with me.